# How to call a MFC dialog in Qt and make communication between them?

Tags: c++, qt, mfc

I have a MainWindow created by Qt and a Dialog created by MFC. When I click a button in MainWindow in Qt, I want to show the Dialog created by MFC. What's more, when I click the buttons in MFC Dialog, the MainWindow should have corresponding responce to the click message. How can I do it? Thank you!

Comment: Quite a weird question ! My bet: redesign (using QtCreator form editor) the MFC form and import (copy/paste) code from MFC event handlers

Comment: Standard Windows communication based on `PostMessage`/`SendMessage` is probably the easiest way to communicate from MFC to Qt. You'd need to override [QWidget::nativeEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#nativeEvent) in your main application window, and assign a message (range), that doesn't collide with messages used by Qt internally. I don't know if those messages are documented.

Comment: Since it is C++ you could actually just create use the `CDialog`class as you would with any other class. Nevertheless, why not use a Qt dialog?

Comment: @SebastianLange: your approach is a bit simplicistic... MFC uses it's own resource mappings and optimized mapping from Windows events to C++ members invocation. Nothing of these are compatible to Qt, AFAIK

Comment: @CapelliC: That's mostly, because Qt is highly incompatible with Windows. Not really MFC's fault.

Comment: @IInspectable: Qt incompatible with Windows ? I assume you're kidding...

Comment: @CapelliC: *"I assume you're kidding..."* - Let me assume, that you never tried to implement a **reliable** keyboard user interface in Qt. It's not the only place, where Qt applications on Windows break, but it's the one scenario where it's most obvious, and most easily reproducible. Just work a while with **any** Qt application, and you'll see it drop keyboard input, until you click/tap the application again. Lots of other incompatibilities. No kidding.

Comment: @IInspectable not sure where you encountered this, im developing and using Qt since the early days and never had keyboard troubles. Most applications ran on our machines use Qt and we never had a customer feedback about this nor did we ever encounter this during development or testing period.

Comment: @SebastianLange: You don't get customer feedback for this type of bug, because, in general, customers never even identify this as a bug. They have either been trained to navigate with the mouse exclusively, or they simply click the next input widget, in case the [Tab]-key betrays them. But don't take my word for it. Instead, have a look at Qt's creative interpretation of message handling on Windows. Among other things, it invents its own timestamps for events, and drops the extra info associated with Windows messages. It is broken at the core, and cannot be fixed.